# Laravel Upload Image to img folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Whats the best way for me to upload an image or more with `form class` to my Storage?

Blade:

```
<form class="" action="{{route('newproduct')}}" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="myimage">  <img src="/img/{{$user->myimage}}" height="80" width="80"></label>
          <input type="file" id="myimage" name="myimage"></font>

        </div>

      </div>
```

Controller:

```
   public function NewProduct(Request $request){
      $user = Auth::user();
      $user->myimage= date('mdYHis') . uniqid() . $request->myimage;
      $user->save();
      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Here in my Controller it saves only the random generated name in the DB, but dont upload the file to my Server. I want use this path for saving path:

```
/public/img/
```

Updated Code without image path:

```
    public function NewProduct (Request $request)
      if($request->hasFile('myimage')){
    if ($request->file('myimage')->isValid()) {
      $user = Auth::user();
      $image_name = date('mdYHis') . uniqid() . $request->file('myimage')->getClientOriginalName();
      $user->save();
      return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Need to add to the form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: But i need also an code in my Controller?

Comment: Check and try my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `<form>`

Then, in your controller add this:

```
public function NewProduct(Request $request){
    if($request->hasFile('myimage')){
        if ($request->file('myimage')->isValid()) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $image_name = date('mdYHis') . uniqid() . $request->file('myimage')->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = base_path() . '/public/img';
            $request->file('myimage')->move($path,$image_name);
            $user->myimage = $path.$image_name;
            $user->save();
            return redirect()->back();
        }
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'image not valid');
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'no image');
}
```

For multiple images just need to iterate over the myimage array:

```
public function NewProduct(Request $request){
    if($request->hasFile('myimage')){
        // Do a loop over all images
        foreach ($request->file('myimage') as $image) {
            if ($image->isValid()) {
                $user = Auth::user();
                $image_name = date('mdYHis') . uniqid() . $image->getClientOriginalName();
                $path = base_path() . '/public/img';
                $image->move($path,$image_name);
                $user->myimage = $path.$image_name;
                $user->save();
                return redirect()->back();
            }
        }
        // end loop
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'no image');
}
```

One problem with this approach is that the user will take the last image to store it (All images will be uploaded but the user image path will be the last one).

It can be solved creating a table to store user images paths and saving the image there (one to many relationship)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ';' or '{'

Comment: There is a line before the if statement that doesnt have a `;`

Comment: added but: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: where are you placing the code? let me update it and set up a function instead...

Comment: Works great:) But its save the image as: "/var/www/html/myproject/public/img012320180734575a66d791781e1btcicon.png" where img is without "/" before picture name. why is the path soo long instead of "/img/imagename.png"?

Comment: Because `$user->myimage = $path.$image_name;` takes your server path and the image path and concatenate them. If you only want the `/img/...` just change the path code to this : `$user->myimage = "/img/$image_name";`

Comment: Whats the way for 2 Images with differant names like:              $user->image2= $request->image2;             $user->image3= $request->image3; ?

Comment: Uploading multiple images?

Comment: Thanks:) You helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Blade :

```
<form  action="{{route('newproduct')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="myimage">  
          <input type="file" id="myimage" name="myimage"></font>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Controller :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

  public function NewProduct(Request $request){

        // if request has file
        if($request->hasFile('myimage')){

            $filenameWithExt=$request->file('myimage')->getClientOriginalName();

            $filename=pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);

            $extension=$request->file('myimage')->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $fileNameToStore= date('mdYHis') . uniqid() .$filename.'.'.$extension;

            request()->myimage->move(public_path('img'), $fileNameToStore);  

     }else{
           // if no file from request , then put one no-image.jpeg in public/img folder
           $fileNameToStore='no-image.jpeg'
      }

  $user = Auth::user();
  $user->myimage=$fileNameToStore;
  $user->save();
  return redirect()->back();
  }
```